# Part of the function doesnt run

Tags: javascript

I have this function when a button is clicked but for some reason it stops before the if statement.

Here is the javascript:

```js
    const nextStep = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click')
        let value = e.target.value;
        console.log(value);
        props.setAge(value);
        console.log('set props');

        if(value === 'Yes' && navBarData.isMedicare !== true){

            console.log('went into true')
            //if yes -> continue to medicare routes -> Leave default navbar data
            props.updateMedicareNavBarData();
            console.log('updated medicare prop')
            navigate('/enrolled')
            console.log('nav')

        }  else if (value === 'No' && navBarData.isHealth !== true) {
            //if no -> health care routes -> use health navvar data
            console.log('went into no')
            props.updateHealthNavBarData();
             navigate('/coverage-time')
        }

    }
```

here is the button:

```
<div className=" leading-5 buttonBlock">
                                {buttons.map((button) => (
                                    <button
                                        className="chooseButton border border-blue-500 rounded text-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white hover:shadow-lg hover:shadow-blue-500/50 transition duration-200 font-bold"
                                        key={button.key}
                                        id={button.id}
                                        value={button.value}
                                        onClick={nextStep}
                                    >
                                        {button.title}
                                    </button>
                                ))}
                            </div>
```

and lastly here is my console log:

```html
click - Age.jsx:20 
Yes - Age.jsx:22 
set props -
```

as you can i see i have console logs in the if statement but that doesnt happen, any idea why this is happending?

Comment: That's not possible. I suspect neither `if` condition is true because of the `navBarData` conditions.

Comment: Add `else { console.log("Went into neither"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, both the `if` statement and `else if` statement are false. Make an `else` statement printing something to the console. If it does print, then both conditions above are false- if it doesn't print for some reason (which is unlikely), then there may be another issue. We can cross that bridge if we come to it, though.

Comment: yep i had !== in the first if statement, meaning both if statements are false, thank you!